# Not able to register my ios device on parse for push notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

My device is not getting registered on app installation in swift. I am able to get the device token. But still no device registration.

Comment: What do you mean by device registration?

Comment: Device registration means the device entry in installation table of parse

Comment: Can you you show your code?  Is `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` being called?  is `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` being called?

Comment: But i have solved the issue

Comment: I have to make the entry manually in installation table with device token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below code in the 
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method of app delegate class

```
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.save()
```